# How can I call the AJAX request through dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm trying to make an AJAX request through dropzone but it keeps giving me an error of `No URL provided.` This AJAX request is working in my input field but when I try to insert it in my dropzone it doesn't work

```
<div class="dropzone" id ="drop">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // files is a FileList of File objects
  for (var i = 0, file_name; file_name = files[i]; i++) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
      type: 'post',
      data: file_name,
      processData: false,
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer ACCESS TOKEN",
        "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/' + file_name.name + '","mode": "add"}'
      },
      success: function (data) {
        alert('Success Upload');
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

How can call the AJAX request?

Comment: Why there's a .php? that url is an endpoint in dropbox so that i can upload to my dropbox

Comment: Can you give a snap of your google console on error ? in where the error is triggering ?